# How can I add a textview to a linear layout with an onclick button listener?

Tags: java, android

What I need is for the textview to be added onto a linear layout where it will look organised and nice. Whenever the button is clicked again, it should replace the old textview and update it again.

At the moment, the button onclick listener will produce a textview, but I don't like it because it looks messy and unorganised.

I tried doing this:

`varlinear.addView(varkebabTotal);`

but it caused an error.

I have looked at other examples but they didn't explain how it will work with an onlick listener.

Here's the code for what happens when the button is clicked:

```
varKebab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = "Kebab Wrap";
                if (menu.containsKey(name)) {
                    kebabquantity = list.get(name);

                    if (kebabquantity == null) {
                        kebabquantity = 0;
                    }
                    kebabquantity++;
                    list.put(name, kebabquantity);

                    //kebab qty calc
                     double kebabTotal = kebabquantity * menu.get(name);

                    overallTotal = overallTotal + menu.get(name);
                    varkebabTotal.setText(String.format("%s %s @ £%s = £%.2f", kebabquantity.toString(), name, menu.get(name), kebabTotal));
                    varTotalPrice.setText(String.format("Total = £%.2f", overallTotal));

                    varlinear.addView(varkebabTotal); // this line caused an error


                }

            }
        });
```

Edit:

The error I received is when I tested the app, and when I click the button, the app stops. It shuts itself down due to that one line: `varlinear.addView(varkebabTotal);`

The variables are as follows:

```
varkebabTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kebabTotal);
varTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TotalPrice);
varlinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinear);
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the error you received? Your code also references some variables (e.g `varkebabTotal` and `kebabquantity `) which are not defined in your snippet, it can help to include all relevant code in your question :)

Comment: Thank you chief, I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

one method you can try is to set varkebabTotal.setVisibility(View.GONE); when you initialize the TextView, and then on your onClick event, you can change it to varkebabTotal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: I did what you told me fam, the same thing happens. When I click the button, the android app just stops and crashes

Comment: take out the addView line, and implement the code that i provided.

Comment: Just did that. Now it works like before, it's outputting the text view, but how can i place that inside the linear layout?

Comment: you need to place the actual textView inside the LinearLayout. From there, you can position it using the 'android:layout_gravity' property. If this works, can you go ahead and upvote the answer please